# What is the epsg code of eurostat maps?

Tags: r, epsg

Shape files of Europe maps are available on the [Eurostat website](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units). I downloaded `NUTS_2013_60M_SH`. The tool (readOGR from the R package Rgdal) I use to load the map shows the following proj4string:

```
 "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs"
```

Metadata provided with these files doesn't contain an EPSG code for the projection. I would like to use such a code to define the projection when I load the map.

A [search for RS80 on the spatial reference site](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=grs80) returns several code pages and none seem to be relevant.

What is the EPSG code of the projection used in these Eurostat maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking on https://epsg.io, the only result containing `GRS80` is [EPSG:42310](https://epsg.io/42310), which is a Mercator projection, thus not compatible with `+proj=longlat"`. This confirms the results of your search on http://spatialreference.org/.

<strike>For this reason, I don't think there is an EPSG code for this projection, which is not surprising given that `GRS80` is a fairly outdated CRS (it was soon replaced by the famous `WGS84`).</strike>

EDIT: I tried to load the same file in QGIS, which automatically detected the CRS as EPSG:4258 (which is actually longlat `ETRS89`). The full description is `+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs`.

Comment: The site doesn't find any other GRS80 references because GRS80 is an ellipsoid and not usually used in the name of a coordinate reference system.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no point here to try to deduce the EPSG code from R: it's already hidden in the delivered downloaded data.

How can I say this?

- download the [NUTS-2013-60M-SH.zip](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/geodatafiles/NUTS-2013-60M-SH.zip) file
- unzip it
- find a file `NUTS_2013_60M_SH/data/NUTS_RG_60M_2013.shp.xml`. A file with a `shp.xml` extension is a metadata file associated with each data set produced when you use ArcGIS (I use QGIS but I know this)
- search for a string "EPSG"
- find near a code 4258 (excerpt below indented)

  `...
  <refSysInfo>
  <RefSystem>
    <refSysID>
      <idCodeSpace Sync="TRUE">EPSG</idCodeSpace>
      <idVersion Sync="TRUE">8.2.6</idVersion>
      <identCode code="4258" Sync="TRUE" value="4258"/>
    </refSysID>
  </RefSystem>
  </refSysInfo>
  ...`
- go to https://epsg.io
- search for EPSG 4258
- confirm the extent is Europe http://epsg.io/4258
- see technical detail about the projection at http://etrs89.ensg.ign.fr/

You can also look at `NUTS_2013_60M_SH/data/NUTS_RG_60M_2013.prj`: it contains an ESRI WKT string definition for the projection that match the one available at http://epsg.io/4258

Comment: The point of my question was that eurostat's `shp.xml` file didn't contain an EPSG code.

Comment: `NUTS_RG_60M_2013.prj` did contain a description of the datum `GCS_ETRS_1989`.

Comment: See my answer edited. The EPSG code is here but not the projection string corresponding to it.

Comment: Both EPSG code and projection string were quite hard to find. I have a better idea of the structure of these `.shp.xml` and `.prj` files now.